# Dell PowerConnect 5548P no power to Ubiquiti ER-X

Tags: dell, power-over-ethernet, ubiquiti, powerconnect

I have an old 5548P that I'm trying to add to my current stack. I have an Ubiquiti ER-X that I'm trying to supply power to over PoE, but I'm not getting anything.

- The ER-X pulls 5W, and a port on the 5548P can provide up to 15W, so it's not a supply issue.
- I've done a complete reset and updated the firmware.
- The ER-X powers up fine when supplied with power from the wall.
- I've disabled per-port energy consumption conservation per the [manual](https://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/Common/PowerConnect-5500-Series_UG_en-us.pdf)
- I can see that the device appears as `active` in the port list as a `class0` device.
- The PoE indicator light is solid amber, meaning that power is being delivered.

I'm honestly not sure what the issue could be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm dumb and didn't think of the voltage coming from the switch. An adapter is needed to transform 48V from switch to 24V.

Comment: I was going to say, the Ubiquiti devices often had non-standard PoE injectors that they came with or required. I'm not sure about the latest generation ones but models from a few years back commonly needed special power supply equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Ubiquiti is very loose with the term *PoE*.

The ER-X uses a proprietary 24V variant (as PD and PSE). It's *not* compatible with IEEE PoE as provided by the PowerConnect 5548P.